# How to convert to DataObject with JSONObject that has JSONArray inside

Tags: java, json, parsing, gson

I have json that made of JSONObject that has JSONArray inside.
For example,

```
"value" : {
           "serial":"125",
           "online":"N",
           "menus":[
                   {"menu_name":"name","price":"2000"},{"menu_name":"name","price":"2000"}...
]
}
```

Can I parse this json to data object using Gson??

EDIT : I saw that example but that was Jsonarray that isn't made of jsonobject.

Comment: I saw that example and that is Jsonarray that isn't made of jsonobject.

Comment: I just thinking about just make two data object and handle the object and array separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sure.

```java
public class Value {
    @SerializedName("serial")
    private String serial;
    @SerializedName("online")
    private String online;
    @SerializedName("menus")
    private Menu[] menus;

    // getters, setters
}
public class Menu {
    @SerializedName("menu_name")
    private String menuName;
    @SerializedName("price")
    private String price;

    // getters, setters
}
```

```java
Gson gson = new Gson();
Value result = gson.fromJson(jsonObject, Value.class);
```